# Допустима ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

«С одной стороны, она может означать, что у каждой семьи свои определенные проблемы, и возможно, что они неразрешимы без распада семьи, который был невозможен в те времена, и это увеличивает несчастье, которое копится, пока вся эта масса проблем не приведет к трагическому исходу».

Допустима ли запятая после слова «проблемы» перед союзом «и»?

Comment: What would you decide yourself? Please show your research first.

Comment: Какой из двух союзов "и" имеется в виду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Запятая перед *и это увеличивает* нужна: она разделяет части сложносочинённого предложения.
2. Если текст задумывается как состоящий из трех предложений:

> С одной стороны, она может означать, что у каждой семьи свои определенные проблемы.
>   И возможно, что они неразрешимы без распада семьи, который был невозможен в те времена.
>   И это увеличивает несчастье, которое копится, пока вся эта масса проблем не приведет к трагическому исходу.

то пунктуация должна быть такая:

> «С одной стороны, она может означать, что у каждой семьи свои определенные проблемы, и возможно, что они неразрешимы без распада семьи, который был невозможен в те времена, и это увеличивает несчастье, которое копится, пока вся эта масса проблем не приведет к трагическому исходу».

При этом возникает громоздкое сложносочинённое предложение, состоящее из трёх последовательных предложений, разделённых союзами «и».

3. Если текст задумывается как состоящий из двух предложений:

> С одной стороны, она может означать, что у каждой семьи свои определенные проблемы и, возможно, что они неразрешимы без распада семьи, который был невозможен в те времена.
>   И это увеличивает несчастье, которое копится, пока вся эта масса проблем не приведет к трагическому исходу.

то пунктуация должна быть такая:

> «С одной стороны, она может означать, что у каждой семьи свои определенные проблемы и, возможно, что они неразрешимы без распада семьи, который был невозможен в те времена, -- и это увеличивает несчастье, которое копится, пока вся эта масса проблем не приведет к трагическому исходу».

Здесь запятая перед *и возможно* не нужна. Хотя предложение *что у каждой семьи свои определенные проблемы и, возможно, что они неразрешимы без распада семьи* -- сложносочинённое, оно является подчинённым в более развернутом сложноподчинённом предложении. В этом случае простые предложения, составляющие такое сложносочинённое предложение, запятой не разделяются. А слово *возможно*, как вводное, должно быть выделено запятыми.

PS Сочетание настоящего и прошедшего времени в одном предложении и нагромождение подчинений делают и без того негладкий синтаксис чрезвычайно неудобочитаемым. Если есть такая возможность, хорошо было бы разбить этот текст, по крайней мере, на три предложения.

PPS Я бы посоветовал вам обратить специальное внимание на конструкцию ***возможно***, *неразрешимы без распада, который был* ***невозможен***.

Answer (score 1):

Да, запятая нужна, как и после этого союза.

Comment: перед «и» несомненно

Comment: перед «возможно» - только если «может означать» относится сразу к двум подчиненным предложениям: (есть проблемы и ,возможно, они не разрешимы) 
Если же «и возможно, что они неразрешимы» - независимая фраза, то запятая не нужна.

Comment: @J-mster: Мне кажется, повторение союза «что» указывает на отношение «может означать» к обоим подчиненным предложениям.